# Bootstrap Carousel Indicators Not Changing from Transparent to Solid

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

The carousel indicators on this Bootstrap photo carousel work in that they change the photo appropriately when clicked on; however, they don't work in that if I have clicked on the third carousel indicator, the first carousel indicator remains solid while the third remains transparent. Any ideas on why this might be happening?

```
<div id="photos_overlay">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="cta-overlay col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-sm-6">
                    <h1>Freshwater Ranch</h1>
                    <h4>Freshwater Ranch is located deep within the heart of the Rocky Mountains. The luxury accommodations and equine facilities on this 450-acre ranch were designed to support personal and professional getaways alike, and the awe-inspiring views of the Sawatch and Sangre de Cristo mountain ranges allow for a unique mountain experience. Join us and prepare to be inspired!</h4>
                </div>
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#rotating_photos" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#rotating_photos" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#rotating_photos" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    <li data-target="#rotating_photos" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                </ol>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="photo_body carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="rotating_photos">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="images/ranchhouseview1.jpg" alt="Indoor Arena Photo">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/view4.jpg" alt="Indoor Arena Photo">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/horse.jpg" alt="Horse Photo">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/view5.jpg" alt="Mountain Photo">
            </div>
        </div><!--carousel inner-->
    </div><!--carousel outer-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `carousel-indicators` have to be inside `carousel` div like this:

```
<div class="photo_body carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="rotating_photos">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#rotating_photos" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#rotating_photos" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#rotating_photos" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#rotating_photos" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="images/ranchhouseview1.jpg" alt="Indoor Arena Photo">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/view4.jpg" alt="Indoor Arena Photo">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/horse.jpg" alt="Horse Photo">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/view5.jpg" alt="Mountain Photo">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--carousel inner-->
</div>
<!--carousel outer-->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @makshh. I had moved my indicators inside the .container-fluid div for positioning purposes, and this caused the problem. Moving it back fixed it.